# Multiple Choice on Linear Regression

Tags: r, regression, correlation, self-study

1. Which one is NOT a linear regression models? Please give a 1-2 sentences brief
explanation to your choice.
(a)  $y_i = β_0 +\exp(β_1x_i)+E_i, i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$
(b)  $y_i = β_0 + β_1x_i + β_2 x_{ii} + E_i , i = 1, 2, \ldots, n$
(c)  $y_i =β_0\exp(x_i)+β_2x_i^7 +E_i, i=1, 2,\ldots, n$

2. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ has linear correlation coefficient $r = 0.5$, and there are 77 observations, what is the test statistic for the hypothesis test

$$H0:β_1=0 \quad\text{vs.}\quad Ha:β_1\neq0 $$

where $β_1$ comes from the simple linear regression model below? Please give a 1-2
sentences brief explanation to your choice.   $\quad Y = β_0 + β_1X + E$

(a). Not enough information
(b). 5
(c). 0.25

3. Which model is more possible to have smaller $R^2$? Please give a 1-2 sentences brief explanation to your choice.
A: $Y=β_0+β_1X_1+E$
B: $Y=β_0^*+β_1^*X_1+β_2^*X_2+E^*$
where $Y$ and $X_1$ in model A and B are the same.

(a). Not enough information
(b). Model A
(c). Model B

Comment: I assume that this is homework/self-study related. Please see the following link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812 Try to show us your train of though. Someone just spitting out `b`-`b`-`b` would be quite useless for you anyway. ( `b`-`b`-`b` is not valid answer)

Comment: Welcome to the site. Further to @user11852's comment, please add the [`self-study` tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and take a look at the section on asking questions in the [faq](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq) especially the later part of the section relating to asking questions

Comment: Well, for question three I would think that model B would have a smaller r^2 value because there are more values, so there is a greater chance of correlation.  For question 1 both b and c have terms with an order above 1. And both a and c have terms with exponents. But I am thinking that c is not a linear regression because there is something being multiplied by B0.

Comment: I have edited your question for formatting and clarity (but I have not tried to fix the English errors). Please double check that it still says what you want.

Comment: Thank you! And I have added the self-study tag and commented with my thought process behind the questions. I have spent a lot of time thinking about them and just want to make sure I fully understand the concepts, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

for part(3):

What happens to $R^2$ when we add new predictor variables to a regression model.  Consider the sections on inflation of $R^2$ in this wikipedia article.  The second model is the same as the first model with the addition of a second predictor. What would addition of that predictor do to $R^2$? (If you don't know about adjusted $R^2$ and why we use it, there's a section below the inflation of $R^2$ worth reading too.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination

Answer (score 0):

for part(2):

Since $r=\frac{\sigma_{x,y}}{\sigma_x \sigma_y}$ and $\beta_1=\frac{\sigma_{x,y}}{\sigma^2_x}$;

We have $\beta_1=\frac{\sigma_{x,y}}{\sigma^2_x}=\frac{r. \sigma_x \sigma_y}{\sigma^2_x}=r \frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}$;

Then, $t=\frac{\beta_1}{\sigma_{\beta_1}}$, $r^2=1-\frac{\sum{(y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2}}{\sum{(y_i-\bar{y}_i)^2}}$, and $\sigma_{\beta_1}=\sqrt{ \frac{\sum{(y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2}/(n-2)}{\sum{(x_i-\bar{x}_i)^2}} }$.

From $r^2$ you get:
$\sum{(y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2}= (1-r^2)\sum{(y_i-\bar{y}_i)^2}$. Inserting this into $\sigma_{\beta_1}$ and considering that $\sum{(z_i-\bar{z}_i)^2}=\sigma^2_z n$, we simplify to:

$\sigma_{\beta_1}=\frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x}\sqrt{\frac{1-r^2}{n-2}}$.

Finally,

$t=\frac{r}{\sqrt{\frac{1-r^2}{n-2}}}=\frac{0.5}{\sqrt{\frac{1-0.5^2}{77-2}}}=5$. (b)